# wikipedia api opensearch not working with. json

Tags: wikipedia-api

I am using the wikipedia api to get related images to keywords

For example http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=xml&search=mozart&origin=* is returning me datas and I can extract the image from there.

Changing the format to `json` http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=mozart&origin=* I have a weird result

```
[
    "mozart",
    [
        "Mozart",
        "Mozart and scatology",
        "Mozart in the Jungle",
        "Mozart, l'opéra rock",
        "Mozart effect",
        "Mozart family grand tour",
        "Mozart in Italy",
        "Mozart's nationality",
        "Mozart La Para",
        "Mozarteum University Salzburg"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_and_scatology",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_in_the_Jungle",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart,_l%27op%C3%A9ra_rock",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_effect",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_family_grand_tour",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_in_Italy",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart%27s_nationality",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_La_Para",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozarteum_University_Salzburg"
    ]
]
```

Not really the same format than the xml one.

I know converting xml to json is not really complex but I would like to understand why I can not have the correct output.

And lat me know if you have a better api to get images related to keywords

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) says "On Wikimedia wikis descriptions are disabled due to performance reasons, so the second array only contains empty strings. See T241437." - This explains the empty strings in the json version.

And "Extension:PageImages and $wgPageImagesExpandOpenSearchXml configured as true in LocalSettings.php would allow each item in the XML format to include an  tag with a thumbnail image from the article." - This explains why the images are returned in the xml version.

It's not entirely clear from your question what you are looking for, but for images, the commons api would be better e.g. the API versions of https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart or https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart I presume there's a search API there too.

Comment: Yeah. Don't use `action=opensearch` unless you are developing an OpenSearch client (such as a web browser).